# Expanding environment variables for command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, session-variables

I would like to run a cmd.exe that would evaluate environment variables at call time instead of when it parses the command. If I set the BASE to 2 and echoing it, I should see the number 2, although running this script does not properly set the base.

Expected Behavior:

```
C:\Users\schristo>cmd.exe /X /C "set BASE=2 && echo %BASE% && pause"
2
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Actual behavior:

```
C:\Users\schristo>cmd.exe /X /C "set BASE=2 && echo %BASE% && pause"
%BASE%
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

`cmd.exe /X /V:ON /C "set BASE=2&&echo !BASE!&&pause"`

`/V:ON` enables Delayed Expansion of variables, which is what you need here.  Order of the switches (`/V:ON /C`) matters.

Comment: I missed the /V:ON and !BASE! part.