# Setting and using an environment variable in the same command

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, environment-variables

I am using Windows 7 and I want to set up an environment variable and use it in the same command.
Specifically, I want to execute the following 2 commands simultaneously as a single command-:

```
set MYPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0"
%MYPATH%\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

In other words, I want the Windows version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938483/bash-specifying-environment-variables-for-echo-on-command-line).
This is what I've tried so far -:

```
set MYPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" && cmd.exe /C "%MYPATH%\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
```

But it isn't working.
So, Is there any way of doing this in Windows ?

Comment: `cmd /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"`  <--- this does the same thing.  If it isn't what you want to do then improve your question with actual details.

Comment: @foxidrive Thanks! I tried something like that previously, but it didn't work. So I googled and read somewhere that the only option to do this was to set the path as an environment variable and then call it. The spaces in the path caused a lot of problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by writing -:

```
cmd.exe /X /V:ON /C "set MYPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\varsall.bat" && !MYPATH!"
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9844839/1925388)

Comment: Although I still cannot understand why this is not working - 
`cmd.exe /X /V:ON /C "set MYPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" && !MYPATH!\VC\varsall.bat"`